# How to run a method after v-if in Vue.JS?

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I am wondering how to properly run the method after the HTML fragment is loaded. Let me show you an example, so it would be much clearer:

```
<div v-if="someProp">
    <div class="progress-bar">
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Run method from here to activate progress bar -->   
</div>
<div v-else>
    No method here
</div>
```

Hope I could explain it clearly. Also I want to mention that the progress bar is activated by a jQuery with this method:

`$(.progress-bar).progress()`

I looked through different v-on events, but I could not find the proper one, that would fit my needs. I am perplexed...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just bind to the `updated` method and check if `someProp` is true to execute your jQuery:

```
updated() {
  if (this.someProp) {
    $('.progress-bar').progress()
  }
}
```

Comment: That’s smart, I’ll definitely check it out a bit later, thanks you.

Comment: Working perfectly, ty!